# Decoding swift inheritance data

Tags: swift, multiple-inheritance, decoder

I have a Process class that has a Step type parameter (Step is "abstract"). I have two Step type classes: StepSign and StepReview, as shown in the code:

```
class Process: Codable {
    let steps: Array<Step>
    let actualStep: Step

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case steps, actualStep
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        steps = try container.decode(Array<Step>.self, forKey: .steps)
        actualStep = try container.decode(Step.self, forKey: .actualStep)
    }
}

class Step: Codable {
    var id : Int?
}

class StepSign : Step {
    var name : String?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

class StepReview: Step {
    var isReview: Bool

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isReview
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        isReview = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isReview)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
```

When I try to decode I get the Step, but I would like it to return either StepSign or StepReview. But I don't know how to indicate what type it is since at the time of decoding I don't know.

The problem I have is in the following lines:

```
    steps = try container.decode(Array<Step>.self, forKey: .steps)
    actualStep = try container.decode(Step.self, forKey: .actualStep)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try and decode one of them, if it fails, decode the other?

Comment: Always return objects from the parent class since I don't specify which child it is (and that's what I don't know)